# Find the minimum value of $f(x,y,z)=\frac{x^2}{(x+y)(x+z)}+\frac{y^2}{(y+z)(y+x)}+\frac{z^2}{(z+x)(z+y)}$.

Tags: inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, symmetric-polynomials, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Find the minimum value of $f(x,y,z)=\frac{x^2}{(x+y)(x+z)}+\frac{y^2}{(y+z)(y+x)}+\frac{z^2}{(z+x)(z+y)}$ for all notnegative value of $x,y,z$.

I think that minimum value is $\frac{3}{4}$ when $x=y=z$ but I have no prove.

Comment: from where Comes this Problem?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner my student asked me to help with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{(x+y)(x+z)}\geq\frac{(x+y+z)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(x+y)(x+z)}=\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^2+2xy)}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^2+3xy)}\geq\frac{3}{4},$$
where the last inequality it's $$\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2\geq0.$$
The equality occurs for $x=y=z$, which says that we got a minimal value.

Another way:

We need to prove that:
$$4\sum_{cyc}x^2(y+z)\geq3\prod_{cyc}(x+y)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^2y+x^2z-2xyz)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}z(x-y)^2\geq0.$$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x;y;z)=\frac{(xy+yz+zx)(y-z)^2 + (xy+xz-2yz)^2}{4(x+y)(z+x)(y+z)^2} +\frac{3}{4} \geq \frac{3}{4}$

Equality holds when $x=y=z$

Comment: Why do we have $\frac{(xy+yz+zx)(y-z)^2+(xy+xz-2yz)^2}{4(x+y)(z+x)(y+z)^2}\geqslant0$?

Comment: Frist, I write $f(x;y;z)$ as a Sum Of Squares.

Comment: Then do that.${}$

Comment: Sum Of Squares has the form $f(x;y;z)=S_z (x-y)^2 +S_y (x-z)^2 +S_x (y-z)^2$. Then I try to let it into $f(x;y;z) =\frac{(\sum_{cyc} S_x S_y)(y-z)^2 +g(x;y;z)}{S_y +S_z}$. And we are done!