# Help with inequality problem

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, symmetric-polynomials, sum-of-squares-method

> Given $a$ , $b$ , $c \ge 0$ show that
>   $$\frac{a^2}{(a+b)(a+c)} + \frac{b^2}{(b+a)(b+c)}+ \frac{c^2}{(c+a)(c+b)} \ge \frac{3}{4}.$$

I tried using Titu's lemma on it, resulting in

$$\frac{a^2}{(a+b)(a+c)}+\frac{b^2}{(b+a)(b+c)}+ \frac{c^2}{(c+a)(c+b)}\ge \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2 + 3(ab + bc + ca)} $$

And I am stuck here.

Comment: You state that this is a context math problem.  Please edit your post to provide a reference to the particular exam or text in which this problem appears.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of:[Find the minimum value of $f(x,y,z)=\frac{x^2}{(x+y)(x+z)}+\frac{y^2}{(y+z)(y+x)}+\frac{z^2}{(z+x)(z+y)}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2637671/find-the-minimum-value-of-fx-y-z-fracx2xyxz-fracy2yzyx) See also in an equivalent form: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3113148/515527. I must say that your question is way easier to find by searching and keeping them linked is certainly useful.

Comment: Also, noting that $$ab+bc+ca\le \frac{(a+b+c)^2}3,$$ it is very easy to continue with your approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{(a+b)(a+c)}\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a+b)(a+c)}\geq\frac{3}{4},$$ where the last inequality it's 
$$4\sum_{cyc}(a^2+2ab)\geq3\sum_{cyc}\left(a^2+3ab\right)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^2-ab)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^2-2ab)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^2+b^2-2ab)\geq0$$ or $$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2\geq0.$$

Comment: Can you explain the last step  ?

Comment: @Italian I added something. See now.

Comment: How is $$2a^2 = a^2 + b^2 $$

Comment: @Italian I wrote $\sum\limits_{cyc}2a^2=\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+b^2).$ Because $\sum\limits_{cyc}2a^2=2a^2+2b^2+2c^2=(a^2+b^2)+(b^2+c^2)+(c^2+a^2)=\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+b^2).$

Comment: Okay , that was wonderful . Thanks !

Comment: @Italian You are welcome!

Comment: I got the rest of the proof, but can you just explain please why the first inequality follows from C-S?

Comment: @Asaf Rosemarin I used the following C-S. For positives $b_i$ prove that: $\frac{a_1^2}{b_1}+\frac{a_2^2}{b_2}+...+\frac{a_n^2}{b_n}\geq\frac{(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^2}{b_1+b_2+...+b_n}.$

Comment: Can down-voter explain us why did you do it?

Comment: @Arnaud D This down-voting was before, than  Zacky found that it's duplicate. Nine hours before. Also, in my opinion, to down-vote right solutions it's just to destroy  our forum. Thank you for your interest!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Ah, my bad. Then I don't know.

Comment: @Arnaud D I added something to my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

We need to prove that $$4\sum_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)\geq3\prod_{cyc}(a+b)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}c(a-b)^2\geq0.$$

Comment: @Asaf Rosemarin It's a cyclic sum. For example, for three variables $a$, $b$ and $c$ we have $\sum\limits_{cyc}a=a+b+c,$ $\sum\limits_{cyc}c(a-b)^2=c(a-b)^2+a(b-c)^2+b(c-a)^2.$

Comment: Thank you. very neat solution

Comment: Can down-voter explain us, why did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

As the inequality is homogeneous, making the substitutions $b=\lambda a, c=\mu a$ we have

$$\frac{a^2}{(a+b)(a+c)} + \frac{b^2}{(b+a)(b+c)}+ \frac{c^2}{(c+a)(c+b)} = \frac{\lambda ^2 \mu +\lambda ^2+\lambda  \mu ^2+\lambda +\mu ^2+\mu }{(\lambda +1) (\mu +1) (\lambda +\mu )} = f(\lambda,\mu)
$$
with stationary points as the solutions $(\lambda^*,\mu^*)$ for

$$
\nabla f = 0\Rightarrow \cases{\lambda ^2 \mu -\mu ^2 = 0\\ \lambda ^2-\lambda  \mu ^2=0}
$$

now  discarding the solution $\lambda=0,\mu = 0$ we have to demonstrate that $f(\lambda^*,\mu^*)\ge \frac 34$.